# mixed model with repeated measures in R

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I have a crossed design with 2 levels of Trt1 fully crossed with 5 levels of Trt2. This same design is applied at 10 different locations.   Now the samples are collected from the same subjects at 6 different times within 2 years from all treatments.  So i have Trt1 and 2 as main effects.  10 locations as main effects.  And 6 sampling times - repeated measures??

Here is the mixed model
`lmer(response ~Trt1*Trt2*Location+(1|Subject) + (1|Year:Month),  data=Data)`

I want to see the effects of treatment 1 and 2 their interactions and how their effects change at different locations. I am not much concerned about how the effect changes at different times because it is dependent on seasonal variability and other factors.

Please kindly let me know if the code I have written is appropriate for the research questions I have?

Thanks,